# In Chrome console, how can I copy only the statements I entered

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Often while developing I try executing javascript in the console. After 10 or line 20 executions I need the executed lines to include in my script.

My question is, how to get the list of what I have executed copied from console, instead of having the mix of info and executed statements?

Is there an easier way to testing JavaScript? can I have the JS script separately and just re-execute the script while I am testing for development?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en

Comment: @BryanChen This should be an answer that Arjang can mark as accepted.